# Returning data from Python to node.js

Tags: python, node.js

I've been following along with a couple examples I found to call a Python script from Node. I'm able to execute the script, but I can't return data from Python.

test.js

```
var sys   = require('sys'),
    spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    dummy  = spawn('python', ['test.py']);

dummy.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
sys.print("testing...\n");
sys.print(data);
});
```

test.py

```
import time
def dummy() :
    out = '';
    for i in range(0,10) :
        out += str(i + 1) + "\n"
        time.sleep(0.1)
    print out
    return out
if __name__ =='__main__' :
    dummy = dummy()
```

Could someone provide an example of how to return the results from test.py to test.js?

Thanks.

Note: test.py edited for proper indent.

Comment: I think my question comes down to this: How do I either return a value from python's main() (if __name__ == '__main__'), or how do I call a specific python method (dummy()) from Node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out how to do this, by printing the data in Python, and "listening" for the print in Node using stdout.on().

test.js

```
var sys   = require('sys'),
    spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    dummy  = spawn('python', ['test.py']);

dummy.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    sys.print(data.toString());
});
```

test.py

```
import time
def dummy() :
    out = '';
    for i in range(0,10) :
        out += str(i + 1) + ", "
        time.sleep(0.1)
    print out
if __name__ =='__main__' :
    dummy = dummy()
```

Answer (score 3):

As the Sys is deprecated, we can use util. Please find the modified code using util

*test.js*

```
var sys   = require('util'),
    spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    dummy  = spawn('python', ['test.py']);

dummy.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
});
```

*test.py*

```
import time
def dummy() :
    out = '';
    for i in range(0,10) :
        out += str(i + 1) + ", "
        time.sleep(0.1)
    print out
if __name__ =='__main__' :
    dummy = dummy()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your test.py has bug. You should check again for the indents, then run `python test.py` in your terminal to see if it print 1 to 10 or not:

```
import time
def dummy() :
  out = '';
  for i in range(0,10) :
    out += str(i + 1) + "\n"
    time.sleep(0.1)
  print out
  return out

if __name__ =='__main__' :
    dummy = dummy()
```

You should redirect both stdout, stderr to parent process, that help you quickly identify the bug:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
var dummy  = spawn('python', ['test.py']);

dummy.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
dummy.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ran python test.py and it did print 1 - 10.

Comment: Did you get any message when run node test.js?

Comment: No, there are no errors or messages. Both test.js and test.py seem to complete normally.

Comment: as I see, the python code in your question has wrong indent. And if test.js is not print result, I think this line of code `dummy.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);` would print the error.

Comment: Oh, I see what happened. You are right, the indents in my post aren't correct. I went back and looked at the code in my editor, and it runs fine. I didn't indent properly after I copied/pasted for my original post. So, when I run the code as I posted above, I do get an error, as you say. When I run it as it is in my editor, with proper indents, I see 1 - 10 printed out.

My apologies for the improper indents in my post.